# Way to Edit data without changing current Site Visit ID Using Angular+ Spring boot+ MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, angular, spring-boot

I am coding a web application for a service management system. Here, I need to create site visits.

Once I create a site visit, It should be enabled for editing and the editing should be done according to the site Visit Id. The Site visit ID should not be changed. Therefore, I tried to code an auto-fill feature for the site visit ID and remove the text box that allows entering the site visit id in the editing forum. However, the changes I made during editing were not saved.

Then, I attempted another method. If I enter an incorrect site visit Id, then it should not be changed and It should be displayed as "Incorrect site visit ID ". Now all the changes done by me are saved properly when site visit ID is correct. But still it doesn't display the message " Incorrect site visit ID" when the ID is incorrect. Instead It gives the message "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/siteVisit/update: 500 OK ". Additionally If the incorrect site visit ID is available in another site visit that I created previously, the data according to that site visit id is changed.

I need to fix these errors. I used Angular , spring boot and MySQL for development. Please help me because I am a beginner. [image]

Backend
SiteVisitResource.java

```
        @PutMapping("/update")
        public ResponseEntity<SiteVisit>updateSiteVisit(@RequestBody SiteVisit siteVisit){
            SiteVisit updateSiteVisit=siteVisitService.updateSiteVisit(siteVisit);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(updateSiteVisit, HttpStatus.CREATED);

        }
```

SitVisitService.java

```
        public SiteVisit updateSiteVisit(SiteVisit siteVisit){

            return siteVisitRepo.save(siteVisit);
        }
```

Frontend
Component.html

```
<!-- Edit Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="updateSiteVisitModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="siteVisitEditModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="updateSiteVisitModalLabel">Edit Site Visit {{editSiteVisits?.siteVisitId}}</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
           </div>

           <div class="modal-body">
              <form #editForm="ngForm">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">SiteVisitId</label>
                    <input type="text" ngModel="{{editSiteVisits?.siteVisitId}}" name="siteVisitId" class="form-control" id="siteVisitId" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="siteVisitId">
                  </div> 

                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="scheduledDate">Scheduled Date</label>
                    <input type="date" ngModel="{{editSiteVisits?.scheduledDate}}" name="scheduledDate" class="form-control" id="scheduledDate" placeholder="scheduledDate">
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="assignedTeamId">Assigned Team Id</label>
                    <input type="text" ngModel="{{editSiteVisits?.assignedTeamId}}" name="assignedTeamId" class="form-control" id="assignedTeamId" placeholder="assignedTeamId">
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="assignedVehicle">Assigned Vehicle</label>
                    <input type="text" ngModel="{{editSiteVisits?.assignedVehicle}}" name="assignedVehicle" class="form-control" id="assignedVehicle" name="assignedVehicle" placeholder="assignedVehicle">
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dateRange">End Date</label>
                    <input type="date" ngModel="{{editSiteVisits?.dateRange}}" name="dateRange" class="form-control" id="dateRange" placeholder="dateRange">
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="state">Status</label>
                    <input type="text" ngModel="{{editSiteVisits?.state}}" name="state" class="form-control" id="state" placeholder="state">
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
                    <button (click)="onUpdateSiteVisit(editForm.value)" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Save changes
                      </button>
                      <p *ngIf="!editSiteVisits?.siteVisitId" class="text-danger">Please enter a siteVisitId.</p>
                      
                 </div>
              </form>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Component.ts

```
   //Edit asite visit
  public onUpdateSiteVisit(siteVisit: SiteVisit): void {
    
    this.siteVisitService.updateSiteVisit(siteVisit).subscribe(
      (response: SiteVisit) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.getSiteVisits();
        
      
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: 500 is an internal server error. Look into your server logfiles and you should find a message the shows the reason of the error